# Fractions of powers of primes.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

I'm wondering whether the following statement is true: Let $p$ and $q$ be two prime numbers (or more generally let $p$ and $q\neq 0$ be integers with $\gcd(p,q)=1$). Then for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exist an $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\Bigg|\frac{p^n}{q^m}-1\Bigg|<\varepsilon.$$

Intuitively at least I'm convinced this should be true. Also experimentally it seems to hold. Is this a known result? If so, hints on how to show this are welcome.

Comment: Why would it not hold for $p,q$ such that $\gcd(p,q)>1$?

Comment: I have no argument for that restriction other than that experimentally I found it harder to justify this claim if $\text{gcd}(p,q)>1$. And I starting wonder about this for prime numbers first. And clearly, it's not a necessary condition.

Comment: It seems intuitive that for every $[p,q,\epsilon]$, you should simply take $n=1$ and a large enough $m$, and you're done.

Comment: @barakmanos That would make $|p^n/q^m-1|$ close to $1$, not to $0$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Ohh, Oops :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking whether for all $\varepsilon>0$ there are $m,n$ such that $\left|\frac{p^n}{q^m}-1\right|<\varepsilon$ is equivalent to asking whether for all $\varepsilon>0$ there are $m,n$ such that $\left|n\log(p) - m\log(q)\right|<\varepsilon$, or, if we prefer, such that $\left|\frac{\log(p)}{\log(q)} - \frac{m}{n}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ (the $\varepsilon$ is different in all three cases, but the $\forall\varepsilon$ statements are equivalent).  This, in turn, follows from the irrationality of $\frac{\log(p)}{\log(q)}$ and a well-known theorem by Dirichlet (or a standard fact on continued fractions) on approximation of irrationals by rationals.

(I'm just sketching the proof since you were asking for a hint.)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed to know. I feel kind of stupid for not taking logarithms, that makes this a very easy problem.